# Inserting 'ENUM' in MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, enums

I would like to know how can I insert an 'enum' type in a mysqli query. I mean, if the field type is string and I execute a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO 'table'(field1,field2) VALUES ('?,?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$value1,$value2);
$stmt->execute();`
```

Everything is ok, but if I change 'field2' to enum type :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
    field1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    field2 ENUM('Administrator', 'User', 'Guest'
);
```

Then this query inserts the first field but the second one is empty. I have checked that the second field value is one of the ENUM type defined.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't actually answer because of incorrect duplications, plus I know you probably already figure out the answer, make sure there is no type-os in anything. I can't help much since this comment is more restricted then answering.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined the options for `ENUM`.

Also, you are inserting values into it.

As far as you enter pre-defined values, in your case:

```
('Administrator', 'User', 'Guest')
```

You can insert `ENUM` field as if it were a string, it will not create a problem.

If you enter any value other than the ones defined e.g. `Administrator`, ... the database will cause error.

Comment: You were right, enum type is inserted like a string value. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 INSERT INTO 'table'(field1,field2) VALUES ('?,?');
```

to

```
 INSERT INTO 'table'(field1,field2) VALUES (?,?);
```

Comment: Errrrr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have seen that you have marked this answer as duplicate and I don't really see why it would be a duplicate. Could you explain how this question and that one is the same?

Comment: @JonathanJ.Pecany Already has an answer [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27290373/2310830) But agree I may have been too quick on the draw as I guess I saw the invalid use of single quotes and assumed that was the error

Comment: @RiggsFolly we all jump to conclusions like that one point or another.

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem, here it goes:

I was saving special char in the enum type (accent)

`field2 ENUM('Administrator', 'Usér', 'Guest');`

and when my query was trying to insert `Us&eacute;r` it fails. So I changed table definition to this:

`field2 ENUM('Administrator', 'Us&eacute;r', 'Guest');` and now everything is working fine.

Thank you for your responses and time.